# Install an exe in azure virtual machine created in resource manager portal

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I am new to azure RM model.Please help me to copy and install an exe in VM created in resource manager portal using powershell script or using API. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you connect to the VM using RDP and copy/install the exe?

Comment: I need to install the exe via powershell script or using API.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do the install the EXE remotely then the VM needs to be configured to allow for remote management - you can do this via WinRM.  See: https://www.penflip.com/powershellorg/secrets-of-powershell-remoting/blob/master/accessing-remote-computers.txt and http://tarkus.me/post/64761019099/windows-azure-vms-remote-management

Setting this up is non-trivial (you need to ensure it's secure).  You could also try adding an VM extension to the VM that will do the copy.  Since the VM is already provision I think the only option here would be to use DSC though I've never added a DSC extension to a VM post-provisioning, it should work.  That would require authoring and staging a DSC script in addition to adding the extension but definitely less complex than enabling remote management.

Simplest by far is as Gaurav suggested and log on to the VM and copy from there.

Comment: As in classic model Get-AzureWinRMUri I couldn't find any commands supported for resource manager portal. Then how could I use WinRM for accesing VM remotely. Please let me know is there any solutions

Comment: You would need to enable WinRM by logging into the VM.  You might be able to use PowerShell to change the VM properties but I've not tried that approach (some properties cannot be changed on an existing VM that way).