# How do you install an exe file stored in Azure File shares on Azure VMs using DSC?

Tags: powershell, azure, virtual-machine, dsc, azure-files

I have some .exe files which i need to install on VMs in azure using azure automation powershell DSC. Is this possible and how can it be done? The exe files are currently stored in an azure file share.

Comment: nobody knows how to do this???

Comment: Was the provided answer helpful to you by any chance ?

Answer (score 0):

A similar question was asked [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34868976/install-an-exe-in-azure-virtual-machine-created-in-resource-manager-portal) The answer provided was:

*If you want to do the install the EXE remotely then the VM needs to be configured to allow for remote management - you can do this via WinRM. See: https://www.penflip.com/powershellorg/secrets-of-powershell-remoting/blob/master/accessing-remote-computers.txt and http://tarkus.me/post/64761019099/windows-azure-vms-remote-management
Setting this up is non-trivial (you need to ensure it's secure). You could also try adding an VM extension to the VM that will do the copy. Since the VM is already provision I think the only option here would be to use DSC though I've never added a DSC extension to a VM post-provisioning, it should work. That would require authoring and staging a DSC script in addition to adding the extension but definitely less complex than enabling remote management.*

You should also consider Azure automation, depending on how large scale is your automation projects are. You can find more info and tutorials [**here**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-intro)